# Starting Ubuntu without Admin Account password

Tags: login, password

Can we start to use Ubuntu, into the main administrator (Root) account, without to have to enter the password?

I know it is intended for security reasons, but... Please! I'm just a church musician and I don't have any kind of "Top Secret" and/or hidden material into this device. Also, I'm the only one which uses this PC, so...

Do I really need that "password way" to enter to my PC?

Whatever, if there is a way to "jump" the password, Please! Let me know!

The screen I get from the "Users & Groups" system configuration menu is:

[image]

Comment: You don't appear to know what the user root is. Please specify whether you want to log into your graphical desktop environment without entering your password when you start your PC or whether you want to execute commands as root or with root privileges without having to ender the password of rood or the sudoer account you're using.

Comment: I'm not talking about the terminal sudo command. I'm talking about the moment when I power on my PC. The system runs its starting process up... the point when I have to enter the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't log in to the root account (well, normally), nor should you. Please don't override this security precaution.

If you just want to log in without having any sort of password authentication, that is very easily available to you. If you go to **System Settings** and click on **User Accounts**, you'll have this screen displayed to you:

[image]

Simply make sure Automatic Login is turned on, and your system will always automatically log you in.

---

If you're talking about bypassing the need for a `sudo` password, that is still doable but less of a good idea. In a single-user environment, `sudo` is primarily a "sanity check" to add some resistance to any action that could be potentially dangerous or make your system not work as well. Or, in other words, it's the "Yeah, I'm sure about what I'm doing" command. That, and if you disable `sudo` password enforcement, you open a rather broad attack vector to malware and the like.

If you still want to do this, simply open a terminal and type `sudo visudo`. From there, add this line to the `User privilege specification` section:

```
<your user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Be sure to replace `<your user>` with your username on the computer.

Comment: I don't have the option "Automatic Login" in the panel I have here. I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS. Maybe there is some changes on this? ???

Comment: @Juan Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: I uploaded an image from my system "Users & Groups" menu panel into the main question text. Please, I'm chilean, so all is written in spanish, sorry.

Comment: @Juan No worries, Google Translate is useful. Click "change" by the password section and see if there's an option for auto-login. Perhaps a "don't ask on login" or similar?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I found the solution into that second panel: "Don't ask on login". Thank you so much, again!!!